# Is there any document about rules to validate HTML of W3 validator tool?

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I am finding a document of rules which are applied at http://validator.w3.org/ to apply to my html sources. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get a source code of markup validator here, they use dtd's to validate your document

http://validator.w3.org/source/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't see any rule about HTML/CSS coding conventions here. Could you give me more details please?

Comment: `DTD` contains different set of rules, like strict, loose, frameset etc, so your document is parsed according the dtd you've specified at the very top of the document, so when you validate, w3c actually applies rules which are mentioned in the dtd and thus it throws you errors if your document is invalid

Answer (score 2):

For the experimental HTML5 feature of the validator, the rules are the rules in the HTML5 drafts, either W3C HTML5 or WHATWG HTML Living Standard documents. Those rules may change without prior notice, and the validator does not always match the current state of the drafts.

Otherwise, in validation proper, i.e. SGML or XML validation, the rules are defined by your document. The document type declaration, i.e. `doctype` declaration, identifies the document type definition (DTD) to be used. In addition, general SGML or XML parsing rules are applied. For a more detailed description, refer to my page *[“HTML validation” is a good tool, but just a tool](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/validation.html)*.